# SOLR find documents that don't match join

Tags: solr

Don't know how to put this in words, so i'll try with an example:

Imagine two types of documents, **A** and **B**, both have an **id** and a **name**.

```
A
a_id
a_name

B
b_id
b_name
```

Documents of type A can have 0 or more documents of type B attached, so if I want to query documents of type A related to documents of type B with name 'earth', I'll do:

```
_query_:\"{!join from=b_id to=a_id} (b_name:(earth))"
```

and it works just fine.

Now, how could I find documents of type A that aren't related to any document of type B?

I've tried

```
_query_:\"{!join from=b_id to=a_id} (-b_id:[* TO *])"
```

but it doesn't work, probably because is still trying to do a join or something.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
q=-_query_:"{!join from=b_id to=a_id}*:*"
```